# Use variable in google map

Tags: google-maps

I am using this code below. When my users login and input there adderess I want to display their location on a map.

```
    <?php
// Get lat and long by address
$dlocation = '2286 Wellman Place,Oak Harbor,WA';
$address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
echo $latitude;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#map {
            position: relative;
        }

        div#crosshair {
            position: absolute;
            top: 192px;
            height: 19px;
            width: 19px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -8px;
            display: block;
            /* background: url(crosshair.gif); */
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        var centerChangedLast;
        var reverseGeocodedLast;
        var currentReverseGeocodeResponse;

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.258545,-122.7399284);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Hello World!"
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width:700px; height:800px">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:800px"></div>
    <div id="crosshair"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

When I try to replace 48.258545,-122.7399284 with the variables $latitude and $longitude the map does not load.
What do I need to change so it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use php vars in javascript you must echo the result

```
       function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $latitude . ',' . $longitude ?>);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

or assign  the php var value to javascript vars

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var centerChangedLast;
    var my_latitude = <?= $latitude ?>;
    var my_longitude = <?= $longitude ?>;
   .......

        .....
       function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(my_latitude , my_longitude );
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I had to change mylatitude to my_latitude

Comment: @Macca424  your comment have not sense .. this is  googlemaps  ..  try explain better